# Print Class Name, Method name and line number using Logger's info()

Tags: java, logging, logback

I already configured logback file to get classname, method name and line number.

```
 <pattern> %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %class{36}.%M %L - %msg%n </pattern>
```

I want to print log message when entering and existing method. How can i do that within the class using info() method. I used the code below. But it didnt print what i wanted.

I use org.slf4j.Logger and Logback logging

```
LOG.info("Entering " + );
```

This is what I got :

```
14:41:48.097 [main] INFO  c.a.j.orgchart.CsvPersonReader - Entering
```

I want to print something like this:

```
14:41:48.097 [main] INFO  c.a.j.orgchart.CsvPersonReader.[MethodName] [Linenumber] - Entering
```

Comment: `But it didnt print what i wanted. ` What do you want?

Comment: You will need to provide more information about the underlying logger framework employed. Surely with proper configuration you will get what you want without need of additional code. The standard java logging api? Log4j?

Comment: @copeg  This is what i got 
14:41:48.097 [main] INFO c.a.j.orgchart.CsvPersonReader - Entering
But I want  14:41:48.097 [main] INFO c.a.j.orgchart.CsvPersonReader. MethodName  LineNumber - Entering

Comment: I think you have to just write the method name too in the message being logged. I use something like this in most of the logs I create  " myMethod -- Entering "

Comment: @Victor I just updated the original post.

Comment: Can you show that you are using the correct logger? Also, you need to compile your code to include line numbers. They aren't always available.

Comment: What is `LOG` in `LOG.info(..)`?

Comment: @user2033382 checks this out : http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html, perhaps could help.

Comment: Guys, do we have an answer here??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
     <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level  %class{36}.%M %L  - %msg%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: What changed? Can you explain how this differs from what you had previously? (Especially your pattern which looks the same.)

Comment: %logger{40}  can be used to get the tagName LoggerFactory.getLogger(tagName)   example of tagName MyClass.class.getSimpleName()

Comment: Does logback use reflection to achieve this ? To print class name, method name etc ?

Answer (score 1):

```
logging.pattern.console=%14date{dd.MM.yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS} [%1level] %30.30logger{1}\.%replace(%replace(%replace(%caller{3..4}){'[\n\r]',''}){'\\(.+\\)$','()'}){'^.+\\.',''} : %msg%n
```

Above pattern outputs result like below:

```
10.05.2019 08:35:05.337 [INFO] epositoryConfigurationDelegate.forEach() : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
...
```

Here's another option if you want to printout little a bit polished version of it.

```
logging.pattern.console=%14date{dd.MM.yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS} [%1level] %40.40logger{0}\.%-35.35replace(%replace(%replace(%caller{3..4}){'[\n\r]',''}){'\\(.+\\)$','()'}){'^.+\\.',''} : %msg%n
```

Output looks like this:

```
10.05.2019 08:45:57.228 [DEBUG]                 RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.forEach()                           : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
10.05.2019 08:45:59.651 [INFO]          RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.forEach()                           : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 384ms. Found 3 repository interfaces.
10.05.2019 08:46:00.524 [INFO] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker.doCreateBean()                      : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f00c757] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
10.05.2019 08:46:03.828 [INFO]                          TomcatWebServer.getWebServer()                      : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
10.05.2019 08:46:03.896 [INFO]                          StandardService.start()                             : Starting service [Tomcat]
10.05.2019 08:46:03.897 [INFO]                           StandardEngine.start()                             : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
```

1

> Just keep in mind that "...Generating the caller class information is
>   not particularly fast. ..."
>
> [logback patternlayout docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout)